# Queries on case when statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

During my insertion of case when statement, the oracle will auto insert another '0' behind any fixed number due to my case when.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO test
            (test_date,
             testno,
             hours)
 SELECT '20-OCT-2010',
       '1234',
       CASE
         WHEN Extract(DAY FROM( endtime - starttime )) >= 1 THEN (
         Extract(DAY FROM(
                         endtime - starttime ))
         * 24 + Extract
         (HOUR FROM(
       endtime - starttime
       )) )
         WHEN starttime IS NULL
              AND endtime IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE ( Extract(HOUR FROM( endtime - starttime )) )
       END
       ||''
       || CASE
            WHEN endtime IS NULL
                 AND starttime IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE Extract(MINUTE FROM ( endtime - starttime )) / 60
          END AS hours
FROM   testtime
```

My results executed from the above statement:

```
Test_Date         TestNo           Hours
20-OCT-2010        1234            140
```

Expected results:

```
Test_Date         TestNo           Hours
20-OCT-2010        1234            14
```

My data type for hours is number (4,2)
My error is due to that if the starttime and endtime for minute is null, it will auto add an '0' behind it. Even i change the '0' to null, it will still add 0 behind.

May i know is there another way to place the '0' value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of concatenating number-of-hours and number-of-minutes,-divided-by-sixty, you should add them. For example, 3 hours and 0 minutes is `3 + 0 = 3` hours, not `3 || 0 = 30` hours.

In other words, change your `||''||` to `+`.

Comment: Hi, i'm not able to change ||''|| to + because my data type is number. so i can't add +. Only numbers

Comment: @user976050: I'm sorry, but I really don't know what you're trying to say. `||` is the string concatenation operator; see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators003.htm. `+` is for numeric addition; see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators002.htm.

Comment: ok. Now i know what you are trying to say. Thanks. All because of my string concatenation. THANKS RUAKH!